# Confluent Kafka S3 sink connector throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions` when using Parquet format

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

When using Confluent S3 sink connector, the following error happens:

```
[2021-08-08 02:25:15,588] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3-test-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover unt
il manually restarted. Error: com/google/common/base/Preconditions (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:607)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.<init>(Configuration.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.<init>(Configuration.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:474)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:345)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:162)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:153)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.builder(AvroParquetWriter.java:43)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider$1.write(ParquetRecordWriterProvider.java:79)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.format.KeyValueHeaderRecordWriterProvider$1.write(KeyValueHeaderRecordWriterProvider.java:105)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:532)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.checkRotationOrAppend(TopicPartitionWriter.java:302)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.executeState(TopicPartitionWriter.java:245)                                                                   at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:196)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:234)                                                                                                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)                                                                   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
```

This happens for 5.5, 10.0.0 and 10.0.1.

It only happens for Parquet, while Arvo works fine.

Logs show that partitioner and source data format works okay.

```
[2021-08-08 02:25:15,564] INFO Opening record writer for: xxxxx/xxxxx.xxxxx.users/year=2021/month=08/day=07/xxxxx.xxxxx.tablename+0+0000000000.snappy.parquet
 (io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider:74)
```

The connector is a manually downloaded from Confluent website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out `hadoop-common` requires `guava` utiltiy from Google, which was somehow missing in the distribution.

You need to locate the [corresponding `guava.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/11.0.2) in [`hadoop-common` Maven repo page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.10.1). Then manually download `guava.jar` to the `lib/` folder of the connector.

It seems there is an entry that [explicitly excluded `guava` from `hadoop-common`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/b456e37d33655f125e840c81c8a2fce49e3e696c/pom.xml#L130-L143) dependency that caused this problem:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
```

This really should have been caught in testing.

Comment: While I agree should have been caught, there's only unit tests, AFAIK, not thorough smoke/integration tests, which may explicitly include hadoop-common in the test scope